# sorted-map returns nil value for existing key

Tags: clojure

I try to get value by key from sorted map with comparator by value it returns `nil`.

```
(def tmap {1 {:v 1} 2 {:v 2} 3 {:v 3}})

(def tmap-sorted
  (apply sorted-map-by
         #(let [val-comp (- (compare
                             (get-in tmap [%1 :v])
                             (get-in tmap [%2 :v])))]
            (if (= val-comp 0)
              1
              val-comp))
         (flatten (vec tmap))))
; => {3 {:v 3} 2 {:v 2} 1 {:v 1}}

(get tmap-sorted 3)
;=> nil
```

Expected: `{:v 3}`

Actual: `nil`

Comment: I don't know about why it's not returning expected value, but ya if u are trying to achieve same then there is one more way.
try these (get (into (sorted-map-by >)  tmap) 3)

Comment: Your comparison function is asymmetric since `(f x y) = 1` and `(f y x) = 1` when `(get-in tmap [x :v]) (get-in tmap [y :v])` is `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) with [`compare`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/compare) that is being used in [`PersistentTreeMap`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentTreeMap.java) (the type of `tmap-sorted`) to lookup the value but your comparator never returns 0 which would mean that two objects are equal.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of equals.

If you modify your comparator to `println` for debug you can see that when compare **3** to **3** you get **1** meaning they are not equal.

```
(def tmap {1 {:v 1} 2 {:v 2} 3 {:v 3}})
(def tmap-sorted (apply
                  sorted-map-by
                  #(let [val-comp
                         (- (compare
                             (get-in tmap [%1 :v])
                             (get-in tmap [%2 :v])))
                         ret (if (= val-comp 0)
                               1
                               val-comp)]
     (println "%1: " %1 " %2: " %2 " ret=" ret)
     ret)
                        (flatten (vec tmap))))


(get tmap-sorted 3)
;; %1:  3  %2:  2  ret= -1
;; %1:  3  %2:  3  ret= 1

(get tmap-sorted 1) 
;; %1:  1  %2:  2  ret= 1
;; %1:  1  %2:  1  ret= 1
```

So you need to fix your `compare` function to work for equality